# How to mock a React Component static method with Jest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, static-methods, react-component

This was really hard to find out how to do. I could not find any code to show you how to mock a static method in a React Component. This way worked for me.

```
// YourComponent.js

class YourComponent extends Component {
  static getHelloWorld () {
    return 'hello world';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{YourComponent.getHelloWorld()}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

```
// YourComponent.test.js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import YourComponent from './YourComponent';

YourComponent.__proto__.getHelloWorld = jest.fn(() => { return 'Hello Universe' });

describe('YourComponent test for mocking static method', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<YourComponent />);

    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('Hello Universe');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

`index.js`:

```js
import { Component } from 'react';

class YourComponent extends Component {
  static getHelloWorld() {
    return 'hello world';
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{YourComponent.getHelloWorld()}</div>;
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import YourComponent from './';

describe('YourComponent test for mocking static method', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    YourComponent.getHelloWorld = jest.fn(() => {
      return 'Hello Universe';
    });
    const wrapper = mount(<YourComponent />);

    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('Hello Universe');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61022182/index.test.js (8.455s)
  YourComponent test for mocking static method
    ✓ should render (30ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   88.89 |      100 |   66.67 |    87.5 |                   
 index.js |   88.89 |      100 |   66.67 |    87.5 | 5                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.327s
```